# Given a list of ranges some with higher priority than others determine the non-overlapping segments

Tags: javascript, algorithm, range

The title of the question may not be completely clear (probably isn't) so let me give an example.

NOTE: The algorithmic approach is described towards the end of the question, but it needs the following examples to be understandable.

Let's say we have 3 ranges:

```
[
  {start: 4.5, end: 9}, // a
  {start: 3.9, end: 9.5}, // b
  {start: 2.5, end: 11.5} // c
]
```

These ranges can be visualized like a video editor as follows:

```
        [  a  ]

      [    b    ]

    [      c       ]
```

I would like to find all the non-overlapping sections of for each range. In the above case I would like an output of:

`c: [{start: 2.5, end: 3.9}, {start: 9.5, end: 11.5}] -> This is from the left edge of c to the left edge of b & the right edge of b to the right edge of c`

`b: [{start: 3.9, end: 4.5}, {start: 9, end: 9.5}] -> This is from the left edge of b to the left edge of a & the right edge of a to the right edge of b`

`a: [{start: 4.5, end: 9}] -> there is no overlap since a is the "highest" layer`

This however is just one case, there could be any amount of layers on a given row, take the following for example:

```
[
  {start: 4.5, end: 5.5}, // a1
  {start: 7.5, end: 8.5}, // a2
  {start: 3.5, end: 9.5} // b
]
```

Visualized as

```
   [ a1 ]    [ a2 ]

 [         b         ]
```

The output should account for the ranges from the left of b to the left of a1, the gap between a1 and a2, and the right edge of a2 to the right edge of b:

`a1: [{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}]`

`a2: [{start: 7.5, end: 8.5}]`

`b: [{start: 3.5, end: 4.5}, {start: 5.5, end: 7.5}, {start: 8.5, end: 9.5}]`

Or another example just to drive the point home

```
[    a      ]

    [       b       ]

 [       c       ]
```

c should have no output since there is no point at which there isn't any other layer above it and b should have an output of the right side of a to the right side of b.

I guess another way to phrase this would be, imagine that there's a light shining straight down, I would like the ranges where the light would hit on each layer. Since a is at the top there would be no blocking, b would receive some light, and c would receive none.

Preferably an answer in JavaScript, but even pseudo-code would do.

Comment: You should edit your question and put the bit about the _light shining straight down_ bit at the top. It explains what you need from your algorithm well. I suppose some will downvote you because you didn't include an attempt. (I did not downvote you). Also **please include different sample inputs with corresponding resulting outputs**

Comment: Have you attempted a solution?

Comment: Where in the input do you define the *names* of the ranges (a, b, c)?

Comment: They don't need defined names, you can conceptualize it as though there's a height property on each object that shows where it is spatially

Comment: It would be better to be concrete. Can we say that the input is ordered from top to bottom?

Comment: Sure. That works

Comment: Something to note is that several ranges can be on the same "row", so a multi-dimensional array will be needed.

Comment: It would be good if you would update the question and introduce this concept explicitly in your examples of input. The comments `// a1` are nice to read, but they are not part of the input. It cannot be the purpose that a change in the comments only (e.g. changing a1 to a and a2 to z) would impact the output you expect, unless if you don't mind that a1 and a2 are considered to have a different height (a1 higher than a2)

Comment: You're right, a1/a2 being on the same level is irrelevant to the actual output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the height of each range is unique and is defined by the opposite of the index, so that the last range in the input is the lowest and the first range in the input is at the top.

You could extract the start and end properties of each range and create a new array where these are "events" that either start a range or end it.

Sort this new array so you can visit each event in non-decreasing order.

Then maintain for each level what its current "open" state is:

- either true, when a "start" event was processed but not yet the corresponding "end" event.
- or false, in all other cases (no "start" event was processed, or the "end" event was processed).

This way you have all you need to build the desired result. I assume that the result will be an array of sub-arrays. The outer array will have just as many elements as the input, so that the input/output matches by index. The inner subarrays will list the ranges that belong to the same level.

```js
function partition(segments) {
    // split ranges into events and sort them
    let events = segments.flatMap(({start, end}, level) => 
        [{ value: start, level, isOpen: true  },
         { value: end,   level, isOpen: false }]
    ).sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
    
    let result = segments.map(() => []);
    let { value: start, level: currentLevel } = events[0];
    let levelIsOpen = Array(segments.length).fill(false);
    levelIsOpen[currentLevel] = true;
    for (let { value, level, isOpen } of events.slice(1)) {
        levelIsOpen[level] = isOpen;
        if (level > currentLevel) continue; // event is not visible
        if (value > start && currentLevel < segments.length) { // only add non-empty ranges
            result[Math.max(currentLevel, level)].push({ start, end: value });
        }
        // Adapt current level (i.e. max visibility of levels)
        if (isOpen) currentLevel = level;
        while (levelIsOpen[currentLevel] === false) currentLevel++;
        start = value;
    }
    return result;
}

// demo
let segments = [
  {start: 4.5, end: 9},
  {start: 3.9, end: 9.5},
  {start: 2.5, end: 11.5}
];

let result = partition(segments);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in the case where there's no overlap at all.
`let segments = [
  {start: 4.5, end: 9},
  {start: 9.2, end: 9.5}
];`

Comment: An extra condition is necessary to allow for this situation. Updated.

Comment: Okay, great! I see that the way you fixed was only to push ranges that are not out of bounds, but to me it seemed that the underlying issue was that the while loop is checking for closed levels, but it mistakenly thinks that events that have not been opened yet are already closed. So the way I fixed it is by adding a check whether or not the current event has been opened and closed already. 

`levelIsOpen[currentLevel] === false &&
        levelHasClosed[currentLevel]`

Comment: That is also a way: my reasoning was: when there is no bottom level at all then the result should leave a gap (and so no push should happen). This happens when the current level is beyond the array size.

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the segments in the output does not matter, then I think we can do this relatively simply:

```js
const aperture = (n) => (xs) => 
  xs .length < n ? [] : [xs .slice (0, n), ... aperture (n) (xs .slice (1))]

const partition = (input) => 
  aperture (2) (
    [... new Set ([... input] .flatMap (({start, end}) => [start, end]))] 
      .sort ((a, b) => a - b)
  ) .map (([start, end]) => ({start, end}))


console .log ('example 1',
  partition ([{start: 4.5, end: 9}, {start: 3.9, end: 9.5}, {start: 2.5, end: 11.5}])
)

console .log ('example 2',
  partition ([{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}, {start: 7.5, end: 8.5}, {start: 3.5, end: 9.5}])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`aperture`** essentially moves a sliding window of length `n` over an array of values, yielding a number of smaller arrays.  For instance,

```js
aperture (3) ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) 
//=> [[8, 6, 7], [6, 7, 5], [7, 5, 3], [5, 3, 0], [3, 0, 9]]
```

Our `partition` function takes all the start and end indices, flattens them out into a single array, removes duplicates (through `[... new Set (<elements>)]`), sorts them numerically, then uses `aperture` to group them into pairs, and then turns those pairs back into `{start, end}` objects.

If this is what you're looking for, none of the layering discussion in the question and comments is particularly relevant.

### Update

It looks as though you are looking to track these by level.  Here's a technique that will do this, probably less efficiently than the technique by trincot, but to my mind somewhat more understandably:

```js
const subtractSeg = ({start: a, end: b}, {start: c, end: d}) => 
  c < a
    ? d < a ? [{start: a, end: b}] : d < b ? [{start: d, end: b}] : []
  : c < b
    ? d < b ? [{start: a, end: c}, {start: d, end: b}] : [{start: a, end: c}]
  : [{start: a, end: b}]

const subtractAllSegs = (seg, segs) =>
  segs .reduce ((a, s) => a .flatMap ((t) => subtractSeg (t, s)), [seg]) 
       .filter (({start, end}) => start < end)

const partition = ([seg, ...segs]) => 
  segs .reduce ((a, s) => [...a, subtractAllSegs(s, a .flat ())], [[seg]])

console .log ('example 1',
  partition ([{start: 4.5, end: 9}, {start: 3.9, end: 9.5}, {start: 2.5, end: 11.5}])
)

console .log ('example 2',
  partition ([{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}, {start: 7.5, end: 8.5}, {start: 3.5, end: 9.5}])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The new `partition` function is built atop one which subtracts a number of segments from one segment, which in turn is built atop one which subtracts one segment from another.  The `.reduce` call in `partition` keeps each level distinct.

This pairs the new segments with the original simply through shared indices.  We could clearly zip these together if you need a more explicit mapping.

#### Deeper Explanation

A comment from the OP found this answer difficult to comprehend.  Here's an attempt at a more complete explanation.

First we have the function `subtractSeg`, which subtracts the contents of one segment from another, leaving zero, one, or two segments in its place.  The function is built out of nested conditional expressions (ternaries) but is in essence just a way to present this diagram in a function:

```
                    Subtracting (c, d) from (a, b)
                    ==============================

----(---)---[===]----  :: c < a && d < a             :: [(a, b)]
    c   d   a   b

----(---[---)===]----  :: c < a && d >= a && d < b   :: [(d, b)]
    c   a   d   b

----(---[---]---)----  :: c < a && d >= a && d >= b  :: []
    c   a   b   d

----[===(---)===]----  :: c >= a && c < b && d < b   :: [(a, c), (d, b)]
    a   c   d   b
      
----[===(---]---)----  :: c >= a c < b && d < b      :: [(a, c)]
    a   c   b   d
      
----[===]---(---)----  :: c >= a c >= b              :: [(a, b)]
    a   b   c   d
```

For this problem, we are simply not worrying about inclusion or exclusion of endpoints, or this would grow additional layers.  Because we have one case (`a < c < d < b`) which yields multiple segments, we wrap all the results in arrays.

Then we write a function to subtract all of a collection of segments from a given segment.  We do this using `reduce`.  The internal `flatMap` is because as seen above, we will sometimes create multiple segments when subtracting one from another.  In this call:

```js
subtractAllSegs ({start: 5, end: 23}, [
  {start: 12, end: 14},
  {start: 2, end: 4},
  {start: 9, end: 15},
  {start: 16, end: 18}
])
```

we first perform `subtractSeg ({start: 5, end: 23}, {start: 12, end: 14})`, yielding `[{start: 5, end: 12}, {start: 14, end: 23}]`.  Then from each of those, we subtract `{start: 2, end: 4}`, which overlaps neither of them, and so gives back the same result.  Then we subtract `{start: 9, end: 15}`, which happens to overlap both, and yields `[{start: 5, end: 9}, {start: 15, end: 23}]`.  Finally we subtract `{start: 16, end: 18}` from both.  It does not overlap the first one, but splits the second in two, yielding `[{start: 5, end: 9}, {start: 15, end: 16}, {start: 18, end: 23}]`.

The `.filter` call simply removes potential detritus of empty segments such as  `{start: 9, end: 9}`.

Finally, our `partition` function looks like this:

```js
const partition = ([seg, ...segs]) => 
  segs .reduce ((a, s) => [...a, subtractAllSegs(s, a .flat ())], [[seg]])
```

We destructure the input array of segments, so that we can deal with the topmost level separately.  We wrap that first layer in a double layer of arrays, and pass it as an initial value into a fold on the remainder.  At each step we take the current segment and subtract from it all the values from every levels above it (combined into a single array by the call to `.flat()`), and push the results as a new subarray of the accumulator.

For example, in this call:

```js
  partition ([{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}, {start: 7.5, end: 8.5}, {start: 3.5, end: 9.5}])
```

We start with this initial value:

```js
[
    [{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}]
]
```

Then we add a second layer by subtracting everything in that top layer from `{start: 7.5, end: 8.5}`.  There is only one thing above it and that doesn't overlap, so our new accumulator looks like this:

```js
[
    [{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}],
    [{start: 7.5, end: 8.5}]
]
```

Now we subtract everything in those two layers from `{start: 2.5, end: 9.5}`, yielding three segments, and a final array that looks like this:

```js
[
    [{start: 4.5, end: 5.5}],
    [{start: 7.5, end: 8.5}]
    [{start: 3.5, end: 4.5}, {start: 5.5, end: 7.5}, {start: 8.5, end: 9.5}]
]
```

The main point of a solution like this is that we break the problem down into manageable chunks.  We write one function to subtract a segment from another.  We use this along with `.reduce`, `.flatMap` and `.filter` to subtract a number of segments from one, and then using the new function with `.reduce` and `.flat`, we can write simple code to transform your original data.  None of these function is particularly complex.  `subtractSeg` is a little obnoxious as we need to test for six different cases, but it still is simple, and the other two are even simpler.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the answer, but I how can I know from the output which input range the output belongs to?

Comment: You can't, and I may have not understood the requirements fully.  How do I know from the plain array input which level the original segments belong to?  Or do you mean to map each index back to the generated output?  I guess it would help if there was a more exact format of the generated output.

Comment: First off, wow. That is an absolute mind-bender to me. It's interesting to see how different people's minds work. For me, @trincot's solution is easier to comprehend, but I suppose people coming from a more functional programming background would find this easier to understand.

Comment: @Jacob: Added a deeper explanation of the updated code.