# multi date range comparing javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, date

I am stuck with figuring out a suitable logic for my issue. I want to create a function that take an array of overlapping dates and divide those dates into a non overlapping array and return it.

Let say I have this array

```
var arr = [
           {start: '2020-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2020-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2020-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' }
          ];
```

Should result in something like this

```
output = [
           {start: '2020-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2020-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2020-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2020-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2020-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2021-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' },
           {start: '2021-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' }
          ]
```

So the result wouldn't  have any overlapping dates. I would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: you misstyped a year in the output

Comment: I'm not sure the logic of your output, I think the algorith you need for this is called Interval Scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take the following approach:

Insert the ranges one-by-one into a non-overlapping array. This reduces the problem to merging a single range with a set of non-overlapping ranges.

I have used "<" and ">" in the code, but you'll probably need to use localeCompare() or similar.

It probably makes sense to implement this for numbers first, make sure it works properly, then convert to date strings in a followup step.

```
function toNonOverlapping(overlapping) {
  let nonOverlapping = []
  for (let i = 0; i < overlapping.length; i++) {
    nonOverlapping = merge(nonOverlapping, overlapping[i]);
  }
  return nonOverlapping
}

/**
 * Merge a new range into an sorted array of non-overlapping ranges, 
 * returning the merged range as a result. 
 * In the process, "processed" parts of newRange are removed.
 */
function merge(nonOverlapping, newRange) {
  if (nonOverlapping.length == 0) {
    return [newRange]
  }
  let result = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < nonOverlapping.length; i++) {
    let current = nonOverlapping[i]

    if (newRange.start > current.end || newRange.end < current.star) {
      // No overlap at all
      result.push_back(current)
    } else {

      // First, handle overlap at the start and reduce newRange acc.
      if (newRange.start < current.start) {
        result.push_back({start: newRange.start, end: current.start})
        newRange.start = current.start
      } else if (newRange.start > current.start) {
        result.push_back({start: current.start, end: newRange.start})
      }

      // Now handle overlap at the end
      if (newRange.end < current.end) {
        result.push_back({start: newRange.start, end: newRange.end})
        result.push_back({start: newRange.end, end: current.end})
      } else if (newRange.end > current.end) {
        result.push_back({start: newRange.start, end: current.end}
        newRange.start = current.end
      }
    }
  }
  // add remainder if anything left
  if (newRange.end > newRaneg.start) {
    result.push_back(newRange)
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: I was trying to go with recursion but I think yours is cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think two helper functions make this pretty simple:

```js
const inPairs = (xs) => 
  [...xs] .reduce ((a, x, i) => i == 0 ? a : [...a, [xs[i - 1], x]], [])

const uniq = (xs) =>
  [... new Set(xs)]

const toIntervals = (ranges) =>
  inPairs (uniq (ranges .flatMap (Object.values)) .sort())
    .map (([start, end]) => ({start, end}))

var arr = [{start: '2020-01-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-01-01T13:34:53.827Z'}, {start: '2020-03-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-03-01T13:34:53.827Z'}, {start: '2020-05-01T13:34:53.827Z' , end: '2021-05-01T13:34:53.827Z'}];

console .log (toIntervals (arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

- **`inPairs`** converts an array into an array of consecutive pairs.  For instance, `inPairs (['f', 'i', 's', 'h'])` yields `[['f', 'i'], ['i', 's'], ['s', 'h']]`.
- **`uniq`** collects an array of all unique inputs from its input, ordered by their first appearance.  For instance, `uniq ([8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 5, 9, 7])` yields `[8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]`.

And our main function is **`toIntervals`**, which collects all start and end values, filters these down to a unique set, sorts them in ascending order, turns them into sequential pairs, and turns those results back into `start`/`end` objects.  (Note that if your input objects have more than these `start`/`end` properties, we will need something slightly more sophisticated than `Object.values`.)

Of course, as both of the helper functions are used only once here, we could choose to inline them, but I've had plenty of needs for both, and all the functions seem simpler with this breakdown.

Comment: A potential flaw in this algorithm is that if ranges don't overlap, a new range will be created between them, e.g. [1,2],[3,4] will turn into [1,2],[2,3],[3,4]. So a check needs to occur to ensure the dates are overlapping. Also, zero–length intervals are treated in one of 3 possible ways, e.g. [1,4],[3,3] becomes [1,3],[3,4], which may or may not be what the OP wants (other alternatives are [1,4] and [1,3],[3,3],[3,4]). Perhaps that can all be dealt with by pre–processing, but I think worth pointing out. :-)

Comment: @RobG: Absolutely right.  I've used this when the non-overlapping is not an issue.  I've never worried about the zero-length case, but the other one probably means this can't be used in many circumstances.

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110504/1243641) can probably be easily adapted to handle this.  It could probably be simplified to not keep these values tied to their original position, but you could also simply flatten the result and resort.

Comment: (That last may not be true.  If I have time later in the day, I'll revisit this.)